# Elastic search multiple fields with Express

Tags: angularjs, express, elasticsearch

I'm new to ElasticSearch and I've been looking all day to figure this out, but I can't seem to make it work.

I'm using AngularJS 1.5x, elasticsearch.js, and Express to do the search. Basically, I have multiple input fields that can be filled in with Strings, or it can be left blank:

{
    name: 'sample name',
    bday: '20080101',
    company: 'XYZ',
    gender: 'F'
}

I'm using POST to search the body. I've been trying to use multi_match query, but I can't make it work.

Thanks in advance